# How to apply tf.case function on a tensor of rank 1 in tensorflow 1.x?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have 2 rank-1 Boolean tensors and I need to apply tf.case to assign a value to the output tensor according to the values of each of the input vectors element by element.
My code is as follows:

```
f1 = lambda: tf.constant(1)
f2 = lambda: tf.constant(2)
f3 = lambda: tf.constant(0)
result = tf.case({c1 : f1, c2 : f2}, default=f3)
```

where *c1* and *c2* are rank-1 tensors, and the output is a tensor of the same shape.

Comment: What's the error, and please provide some data for `c1` and `c2`

Comment: the error message is: 
Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'case/cond/Switch' (op: 'Switch') with input shapes: [?], [?].

Comment: Please provide some dummy data for `c1` and `c2`

Comment: c1 = [True, False, True, False]
c2 = [false, false, false, true]

the two tensors are the outputs of other operations like: tf.less, tf.logical_and....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that worked for this problem is:

```
f1 = tf.math.add(tf.zero_like(c1),1)
f2 = tf.math.add(tf.zero_like(c1),2)
f3 = tf.zero_like(c1)
result = tf.where(c1, f1, f3)
result = tf.where(c2, f2, result)
```

Answer (score 0):

`tf.case()` takes only pairs of **scalar** booleans (**rank-0** tensors) and callables (functions).

In your case, you are passing rank-1 tensors, so you are getting the exception:

> Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'case/cond/Switch'

In order to use non-zero rank tensors with `tf.case`, you have to reduce your tensors first to scalar values.

You might use something like `tf.reduce_all` or `tf.reduce_any` (equivalent to `numpy.all` and `numpy.any`)

```
    x = tf.constant([True,  False]) #your original rank-1 tensor
    c1 = tf.reduce_all(x)           #False: Computes the "logical AND" of all elements
    c2 = tf.reduce_any(x)           #True : Computes the "logical OR" of all elements
    result = tf.case({c1 : f1, c2 : f2}, default=f3) #returns f2
```

Comment: Thank you Mohamed. I think I didn't make my question clear. Here what I want to do:
_x = np.random.randint(100, size=20) 
result = []
for i in range np.shape(x):
    if 10 < x < 30 :
       result = np.append( result, [1], axis=0)
    elif 70 < x < 90:
       result = np.append( result, [2], axis=0) 
    else:
       result = np.append( result, [0], axis=0) 
    resturn result_

So, c1 is a tensor of shape x, and have the value "true" where the first condition is true and "false" elsewhere. Similarly c2 for the second condition.